# Neglect "Returned or Cancelled" rows when calculating total commission

Tags: javascript, php

we are displaying Total commission by calculating with below formula
**Total commission = commission * Number of Rows**

for some rows we have value = "Returned or Cancelled". 
**if value = "Returned or Cancelled"** , we don't want to count those rows for calculating commission.

for below image, now TC = 60, but we need **40** as **1st 2 rows have values Delivered & cancelled.**

[image]

[image]

**php**

```
function getDesignerCollection()
{
foreach($order as $orderData) 
{ 

while ($k < count($orderitemsarray)) 
{ 

if ($orderitemsarray[$k] != '0') 
{ 

$stmtorders = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT * FROM order_details"); 
$stmtorders->execute(array(":dorder_id" => $orderData['entity_id'])); 
$roworders = $stmtorders->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 

if($accountType == "admin")
{ 

    $delivery_status='';
    while($datas = $stmt1->fetch())

{

    $delivery_status=$datas['delivery_status'];

    if($datas['delivery_status']=='P'){$delivery_status='Pending';}
    if($datas['delivery_status']=='D'){$delivery_status='Delivered';}
    if($datas['delivery_status']=='R'){$delivery_status='Returned';}
    if($datas['delivery_status']=='C'){$delivery_status='Cancelled';}
}

$stmt = $user_home->runQuery("SELECT commission1 FROM tbl_users where userID=:uid"); 
$stmt->execute(array(":uid" => $_SESSION['userSession']));
$row = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$commission =  $row['commission1'] ;

$responce[] = array( 
$commission, 
$delivery_status,

); 
}
```

**script**

```
$(".delete_grid").append("Number of rows : "+mygrid.dataset.getSize());

// Total Commission
var numRows=mygrid.dataset.getSize();
var commission =(mygrid.dataset.data[0][8]);
var total_commission=numRows * commission;
$(".delete_grid").append(" ,  Total commission : "+total_commission);


var __TEST_DATA__=eval('<?php
echo getDesignerCollection(); ?>');
var grid_demo_id = "myGrid" ;
var dsOption= {
    fields :[
        {name : 'commission1'  },
        {name : 'delivery_status'  },
    ],
    recordType : 'array',
    data : __TEST_DATA__
}

var colsOption = [  
   {id: 'commission1' , header: "commission1" , width :"80"},
   {id: 'delivery_status' , header: "Deliver Status" , width :"130"},  
];
```

Comment: you need solution in javascript or in php . BTW what is inside `$row`

Comment: @AabirHussain I am okay with both , we are saving `commission` value inside `$commission =  $row['commission1'] ;`

Comment: This will help `SELECT SUM(commission1) FROM tbl_users where userID=:uid AND 'Deliver status' NOT IN ('Delivered','cancelled','Returned')`

Comment: if value = "Returned or Cancelled" , we don't want to count those rows for calculating commission. then commision count would be **30** not **40**

Comment: @Akshay i want to neglect only for `Returned or Cancelled` , i want to include `Delivered`.....

Comment: @Akshay `delivery_status` column in present in `order_details` table , but your query gave `tbl_users` table, can you please give me updated query.....

Comment: @Akshay Thanks a ton , i wil never forget your help.....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var commission=0; 
for (var i = 0; i < mygrid.dataset.data.length; i++) { 
console.log(mygrid.dataset.data[i]); 
if(mygrid.dataset.data[i][10] != "Returned" && mygrid.dataset.data[i][10] !=   "Cancelled"){ 
        commission=commission+parseInt(mygrid.dataset.data[i][8]); 
} 
console.log(commission); 
} 
$(".delete_grid").append(" , Total commission : "+commission);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a variable in php as given below

```
    $delivery_status='';
    $count = 0;
    while($datas = $stmt1->fetch())

{

    $delivery_status=$datas['delivery_status'];

    if($datas['delivery_status']=='P'){$delivery_status='Pending'; }
    if($datas['delivery_status']=='D'){$delivery_status='Delivered';  }
    if($datas['delivery_status']=='R'){$delivery_status='Returned'; }
    if($datas['delivery_status']=='C'){$delivery_status='Cancelled';  }
if($datas['delivery_status'] != 'R' && $datas['delivery_status'] != 'C'){
    $count++;
}

}
```

Now you can count your `totalCommission` as

```
$totalCommission = $count * $commission
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried your code as http://pastebin.com/VJV2Fk7s , i am getting result as `0 for commission`..... also `Notice: Undefined variable: commission ` Notice: Undefined variable: count`

Comment: you have use `$totalCommission = $count * $commission` after `$commission =  $row['commission1'] ;` and `$count = 0;` after `$delivery_status='';` and don't forget to use $count++; as given in the answer

Comment: now i am trying like this : `$totalCommission = $count * $commission;
$commission =  $row['commission1'] ;`  & `$count = 0;
 $delivery_status='';` now giving me the result : `-1` , please check code here : http://pastebin.com/WYfugiyU

Comment: where you are getting `-1` you should return `$totalCommission` and use it where you want to show your data;

Comment: login please remove username & email

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131673/discussion-between-abcd-and-aabir-hussain).